# Why don't lists created with Arrays.asList unbox the values?

Tags: java, arraylist, wrapper, comparator

I have been using `Arrays.asList` to make a two-dimensional ArrayList as follows:

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> li = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    li.add(Arrays.asList(1, (int)(Math.random() * 100)));
}
```

When I try to sort the elements as follows:

```
Collections.sort(li, new Comparator<List<Integer>>(){
    public int compare(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2){
        if(l1.get(0) == l2.get(0)){
            return l1.get(1) - l2.get(1);
        }
        return l1.get(0) - l2.get(0);
    }
});
```

The elements are not sorted correctly by the second index.

However, when I don't use `Arrays.asList`, but create the new ArrayList as such:

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> li = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    ArrayList<Integer> toAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    toAdd.add(1); 
    toAdd.add((int)(Math.random() * 100));
    li.add(toAdd);
}
```

then the sorting works.

I understand that Arrays.asList doesn't copy over the values but is "backed" by the original array. However, shouldn't the `get(0)` call inside the compare function automatically unbox the value?

Comment: Are you sure it works in the second case - you sure it did not just appear to work because the random values made the result appear to be sorted correctly?

Comment: And are you sure it doesn't work in the first case?

Comment: have you tried replacing `==` with `equals`inside the comparator?

Comment: I am getting sorted ArrayList for both of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can spot is the following if-statement:

```
if(l1.get(0) == l2.get(0)) {
}
```

It compares the first index of all lists, which in the given code is always `1`. When you use the `==` operator, you are actually comparing *object references*. Not the equality of their values, but whether two different variables point to the exact same object in memory.

This is okay as long as you compare Integers between -128 and 127. Values within this range are **cached**, hence two different variables of type `Integer` can refer to the same object.

```
Integer a = 127;
Integer b = 127;
System.out.println(a == b); // prints true

Integer c = 128;
Integer d = 128;
System.out.println(c == d); // prints false
```

But because your code stays within the range of cached integers, it should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `==` to compare to `Object` you comparing only references. There is no need to use autounboxing in that case. Moreover Java can sometimes optimizes creating the same objects by creating only once to save heap, therefore comparing by references sometimes works and sometimes don't.